# T does not understand `java.lang.reflect.Type`or java.lang.Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

I want my `T` type to be instance of `java.lang.reflect.Type` interface or `java.lang.Class<T>`

I have created sample code like below

```
public class Car<T extends Type> {
private T t;
public Car(T t) {
    this.t = t;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car<String.class> car = new Car(String.class);//Error String.class
}
}
```

**I know above in above example I can use `Class<T>` instead of using `T`**. I wanted to know if there is any way in which `T` can be made to understand that it is of `Type` or `Class`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Car<String.class>`, write `Car<Class<String>>`.

`String.class` is an **object**. Between the angle brackets you must specify a **type**. The type you're looking for is `Class<String>`.